# jQuery Drag and Drop table row ordering?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Are there any good tutorials for Drag-and-Drop table row ordering with jQuery-UI
or some other plugin? I have been searching and cant seem to find any useful samples.

Of course the order of the items would also need to be persisted to my database in some way...

Comment: So you mean not ordering (as in sorting) but moving single items in the list.

Comment: Yes not sorting. Moving items via drag and drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this plugin: [link text][1] you can order the column and manipulate data from a source with the union of plugin jEditable, you can see a example in Examples > API > Editable Rows (with jEditable).

You can use  draggable with the event Stop

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "sortstop", function(event, ui) {
```

...
});

with the method .sortable( "toArray" ) to get the new order of elements.

You can find examples in the official documentation in: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-stop =)

Comment: I am familiar with that plugin(datatables) but I dont see a way to order ROWS via drag and drop